# how does execlp() system call work?

Tags: unix, operating-system, exec

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(){
pid_t pid;
pid = fork();
if(pid<0){
   fprintf(stderr, "fork failed");
   return 1;    }
else if(pid == 0){  
   execlp("bin/ls", "ls", NULL);}
else{
   wait(NULL);
   printf("child complete\n");
   }
return 0;
}
```

Here as far as I could understand, a child process is created and since its pid returned by fork is "0", it enters the block containing execlp and executes it, and then the parent waits till the child exits and then prints "child complete". Please correct me if I'm wrong. But I didnt understand how execlp() works here. Can someone explain this?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`fork` creates a new process, it is called once by the parent but returns twice in the parent and in the child.

In the child process the call `execlp` executes the specified command `ls`.

This replaces the child process with the new program ﬁle (`ls` program file) which means following.

When a process calls the `execlp` or one of the other 7 `exec` functions, that process is completely replaced by the new program, and the new program starts executing at its main
function.

The process ID does not change across an `exec`, because a new process is not
created. 
`exec` merely replaces the current process's text, data, heap, and stack
segments with a brand new program from disk.

The combination of `fork` followed by `exec` is called `spawning a new process` on some operating systems.

Hopefully it was more or less clear. Let me know if you have more questions.

Comment: Thank you for a nice and helpful answer. :)

Comment: But after running this program, all the directory contents should be published (which is what `ls` do), but all that is published is `child complete`

Comment: @NitinAggarwal the OP has a typo in code. Fix it by `execlp("/bin/ls", "ls", NULL);}`

Answer (score 1):

The  exec() family of functions replaces the current process image with
       a new process image.