# In execlp() system call why the arg0 argument must point to a filename that's associated with the process being started?

Tags: c, unix, operating-system, exec, system-calls

I was going through the Dinosaur book by Galvin et. al. where I came across the following illustration of the `fork()` system call.

```c
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 
int main() 
{ 
     pid_t pid; 
     /* fork a child process */ 
     pid = fork(); 
     if (pid < 0) { /* error occurred */ 
          fprintf(stderr, "Fork Failed"); 
          return 1; 
     } 
     else if (pid == 0) { /* child process */ 
          execlp("/bin/ls","ls",NULL); 
     } 
     else { /* parent process */ 
        /* parent will wait for the child to complete */ 
       wait(NULL); 
       printf("Child Complete"); 
     } 
     return 0; 
}
```

The text says:

> After a `fork()` system call, one of the two processes typically uses the `exec()` system call to replace the process’s memory space with a new program. The `exec()` system call loads a binary file into memory (destroying the memory image of the program containing the `exec()` system call) and starts its execution.

So in this example above :

> The child process then overlays its address space with the UNIX command `/bin/ls` (used to get a directory listing) using the `execlp()` system call (`execlp()` is a version of the `exec()` system call).

---

[Here](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.5.0SP1.update/com.qnx.doc.neutrino_lib_ref/e/execlp.html) it is said that :

```c
   #include <unistd.h>

   int execlp( const char * file, 
               const char * arg0, 
               const char * arg1,
               … 
               const char * argn, 
               NULL );
```

*file*: Used to construct a pathname that identifies the new process image file. If the file argument contains a slash character, the file argument is used as the pathname for the file. Otherwise, the path prefix for this file is obtained by a search of the directories passed as the environment variable PATH.

*arg0, …, argn* : Pointers to NULL-terminated character strings. These strings constitute the argument list available to the new process image. You must terminate the list with a NULL pointer. **The arg0 argument must point to a filename that's associated with the process being started and cannot be NULL.**

Could anyone please explain what are the 3 arguments to the execlp() doing ? More specifically, why the `arg0` must have the same name as the process being started ? The web search said me that the first argument is a file name (or path name) and the rest can be considered as pointers to null terminated strings which act as arguments to the file.

What I do not understand is why we are passing `ls` as an argument to the `ls` program present in the binary folder? While working on Linux terminal with

`$`

in the prompt. Just typing

`$ ls`

and hitting the enter key does the work... I mean we do not give.
`$ ls ls`

Is it similar to the way a C program accepts command line arguments ?

```c
   int main(int argc,char* argv){
    ...
   }
```

Running the binary corresponding to the above program as:
`$ ./a.out xyz pqr`

has `argv[0]="./a.out"` and `argv[1]="xyz"` and `argv[2]="pqr"`. Is `./a.out` an argument to the binary file `a.out`? But using `./a.out` we are actually guiding the Linux system to run the binary.

---

I went [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21558937/7571421) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25992622/7571421) but none of them seem to answer my question directly.

Comment: There is no requirement that `arg0` be the same as the file.  It's just commonly the case.

Comment: The `arg` arguments are what becomes the `argv` array in the program. You can put *anything* there really. That `argv[0]` (and your `arg0`) is the name of the program is traditional.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude @WilliamPursell I changed the arg0 from "ls" to "" and the program works just the same. Only thing is that if I put the arg0 as NULL, the program says `A NULL argv[0] was passed through an exec system call.` I got the point.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude `The arg arguments are what becomes the argv array in the program.` Thanks for the help. `You can put anything there really. That argv[0] (and your arg0) is the name of the program is traditional.` Explicitly in execlp() we can put anything, but in the Linux terminal, argv[0] is automatically taken to be the name of the file. Is this what happens? Because I guess in the Linux terminal we cannot cause `argv[0]` to be as our wish (I do not know it, I might be wrong).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `arg0` parameter is, by convention, the name of the executable being run.  However, this is not required to be the case.  You can pass any string for this argument.